# Is there an equivalent to 'np.r_' in pandas for reordering columns using column indices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe whose info is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 191 entries, 0 to 190
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                    --------------  -----  
 0   Country                   191 non-null    object 
 1   Energy Supply             172 non-null    float64
 2   Energy Supply per Capita  172 non-null    float64
 3   % Renewable               173 non-null    float64
 4   Rank                      191 non-null    int64  
 5   Documents                 191 non-null    int64  
 6   Citable documents         191 non-null    int64  
 7   Citations                 191 non-null    int64  
 8   Self-citations            191 non-null    int64  
 9   Citations per document    191 non-null    float64
 10  H index                   191 non-null    int64  
dtypes: float64(4), int64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 16.5+ KB
```

I want to reorder the columns to:

```
RangeIndex: 191 entries, 0 to 190
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                    Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                    --------------  -----  
 0   Country                   191 non-null    object 
 1   Rank                      191 non-null    int64  
 2   Documents                 191 non-null    int64  
 3   Citable documents         191 non-null    int64  
 4   Citations                 191 non-null    int64  
 5   Self-citations            191 non-null    int64  
 6   Citations per document    191 non-null    float64
 7   H index                   191 non-null    int64  
 8   Energy Supply             172 non-null    float64
 9   Energy Supply per Capita  172 non-null    float64
 10  % Renewable               173 non-null    float64
dtypes: float64(4), int64(6), object(1)
memory usage: 16.5+ KB
```

I used the following code to accomplish this:

```
EnScMerged = pd.merge(Energy,ScimEn, on='Country',how='right').iloc[:,np.r_[0:1, 4:11, 1:4]]
```

I tried to find a panda method earlier and made an attempt which worked:

```
EnScMerged_=EnScMerged.reindex(columns = ['Country','Rank','Documents','Citable documents','Citations','Self-citations','H index','Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita','% Renewable'])
```

I am looking for a way to reorder in the simplest way possible without actually typing out all the column names.  Is there such a way?

Comment: What's wrong with using `np.r_`?

Comment: Look at the output of `r_`.  It's just a way of concatenating several `np.arange`.  It can be convenient, but doesn't do anything unique (even within numpy).

Comment: Thanks....I am new and my experience with numpy almost does not exist....yet!  Happened on the solution here on stack overflow and it worked....not surprised but there is so much to learn!

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it? Otherwise, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `np.r_`, you could rebuild your column index using [`Index.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.append.html) with the pieces of the index you want, and then reindex with that:

```py
cols = EnScMerged.columns
cols = cols[0:1].append(cols[4:11]).append(cols[1:4])
EnScMerged_ = EnScMerged.reindex(columns = cols)
```

Comment: Thanks..worked just as described.....

Comment: @CarlHuxohl no worries - I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

That ``r_` produces an array of numbers:

```
In [16]: idx=np.r_[0:1, 4:11, 1:4];idx
Out[16]: array([ 0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  1,  2,  3])
```

With 11 column names:

```
In [17]: columns = ['Country','Rank','Documents','Citable documents','Citations','Self-citations','H index','H index','Energy Supply','Energy Supply per Capita','% Renewable']
```

That `r_` selects a subset - with some duplicates:

```
In [18]: np.array(columns)[idx]
Out[18]: 
array(['Country', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'H index', 'H index',
       'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', 'Rank',
       'Documents', 'Citable documents'], dtype='<U24')
```

`.iloc` docs says it accepts:

```
An integer, e.g. 5.

A list or array of integers, e.g. [4, 3, 0].

A slice object with ints, e.g. 1:7.

A boolean array.

A callable function with one argument (the calling Series or DataFrame) and that returns valid output for indexing (one of the above). This is useful in method chains, when you don’t have a reference to the calling object, but would like to base your selection on some value.

A tuple of row and column indexes. The tuple elements consist of one of the above inputs, e.g. (0, 1).
```

In your example it gets a tuple, with the 2nd term a list (produced by `r_`).  `iloc` can only accept one slice `1:4`, hence the use of `r_` to convert multiple slices into one array.

Comment: Your list of 11 column names has a duplicate in it (unlike OPs list) hence the duplicate in the output

Comment: @Nick, I was trying to recreate the original column list using the OP's result list as a 'short-cut'.  And got it wrong.